# 「～てこうぜ」は何という意味ですか？

Tags: translation, slang, song-lyrics

In Zukkoke Otokomichi, they translate things like 中ってこうぜ as "Let's ~" Why does こうぜ mean let's? Is it just slang, or does it come from　行こう, just dropping the 行？

Comment: What is 中って??  The word preceding the こうぜ needs to be a verb.

Comment: My phone gave me　中って　instead of 当たって. Any idea why?

Comment: @Anonymous It's an alternate way of writing 当たる, but it's restricted to certain meanings (see [the definition for あたる in 大辞林](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B)) and is much less common.  It's also not included in the [Jōyō kanji chart](http://www.bunka.go.jp/bunkashingikai/soukai/pdf/kaitei_kanji_toushin.pdf), which only includes the readings チュウ／ジュウ and なか for the kanji `中`.  You should usually use 当たる instead.

Comment: With only a B.A., I never knew there was a 中る in my language!  当たってこうぜ means "Let's all be aggressive!".

Answer (score 4):

こうぜ is just how いこうぜ gets pronounced in lively "tough guy" kind of speech.  It is  used in group activities such as sports where a team effort is essential.

Te-form of a verb + （い）こうぜ！ = "Let's all (verb), guys!"